# PySpark Access DataFrame columns at foreachPartition() custom function

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, iterator, pyspark

I have a function named "inside". I want to apply this function to a pyspark dataframe. For this purpose i call the "foreachPartition(inside)" method on the dataframe I create. The "inside" function needs the values of the dataframe.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
>>> small_df
DataFrame[lon: double, lat: double, t: bigint]
```

The code looks like this:

```
def inside(iterator):
    row=iterator
    x=row.lon
    y=row.lat
    i=row.t 
    #do more stuff

small=pliades.iloc[0:20000,:] #take sample of rows from big dataset
small_df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(small) #create dataframe
test=small_df.foreachPartition(inside)
```

My question is: how can x,y,i get the values of the first(lon),second(lat) and third(t) columns of the dataframe respectively?

I tried also doing it with row.lon, row.select, treating it as a list but couldn't get the result needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` operates on `RDD[Row]` and each partitions is `Iterator[Row]`. If you want to have list of all values (not recommended due to possible memory issues

```
def inside(iterator):
    x, y, i = zip(*iterator)
    ...
    yield ...
```

In general it is better to just iterate over rows one by one, without keeping all in memory:

```
def inside(iterator):
    for x, y, i in iterator:
        yield ...
```

You can also consider using `pandas_udf`:

- If function returns the same number of values and only a single column you can use scalar type which takes `pandas.Series` and returns `pandas.Series`

  ```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

  @pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
  def f(*cols: pandas.Series) -> pandas.Series:
      ...

  df.select(f("col1", "col2", ...))
  ```
- Grouped variant which takes `pandas.DataFrame` and returns `pandas.DataFrame` with the same or different number of rows:

  ```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import spark_partition_id



  @pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
  def g(df: pandas.DataFrame) -> pandas.DataFrame:
      ...

  df.groupby(spark_partition_id()).apply(g)
  ```